# Eclipse Maven Plugin not compiling against correct java version

Tags: eclipse, maven, build, pom.xml

I am quite new to using maven and I am using STS as a development environment. I have amended my pom file to indicate that my project should compile with java 7 yet regardless of what I do it always marks the manifest as using jdk 1.6.

```xml
<properties>
    <java-version>1.7</java-version>        
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
         <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.0</version>         
             <configuration>
               <compilerVersion>1.7</compilerVersion>
               <source>1.7</source>
               <target>1.7</target>
             </configuration>
         </plugin>
     </plugins>
 </build>
```

What do I need to do to get it to pick up that my project is 1.7? Here is the text from the manifest for the project which always indicates 1.6:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: pao
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_25
Created-By: Maven Integration for Eclipse
```

Comment: I just wanted to add that now when I run a maven package the manifest in the war file does indicate that the version is java 1.7 but the file in the directory target\m2e-wtp\web-resources\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF always says 1.6....

Comment: Please issue in a terminal `java -version`

Answer (score 0):

The folder target\m2e-wtp\web-resources\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF is generated through the Maven integration you are using inside Eclipse and it is configured to be using JDK 1.6, either default or explicitly.

Change the configuration in your eclipse making sure your project is configured to use jdk 1.7.

Comment: Any pointer on how to do this? My project already uses 1.7 SE files and my project facet is set to 1.7 and also my java compiler setting is set to JDK compliance level JavaSE-1.7. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Do you have a server runtime associated with your project?

Comment: Also, what is your default eclipse jdk set to?

Comment: I didnt but I set it to tomcat 7 just to see if that made a difference but it didnt. If I right click the project and choose export as a war file then the manifest in the generated war has 1.6 as the version, same as in the manifest file within target\m2e-wtp\web-resources\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF, however building the war using a maven: package I get the correct java version in the manifest of the generated war file.

Comment: The default jdk for my eclipse is set to 1.6 I think, at least that is what I selected when I installed it ages ago but I thought I had changed that for this project. HOw do I check the default JDK version?

Comment: In Window->Preferences you have Installed JREs under Java. The one selected with a checkbox is your default. If you have it set to 1.6 try 1.7 and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: No sorry I was just not understanding what you meant, terminology wise, it was checked at 1.7, and now I have actually removed all jdk's except for 1.7 from eclipse completely... yet still that manifest file reports the version as java 1.6. Even if I delete that file it instantly gets recreated and has java 1.6 as the version. Its quite irritating.

Comment: Do you have any server runtimes installed?

Comment: Yes I have the standard one that comes with STS plus tomcat 6 and tomcat 7 stand alones configured to be used within STS. Would this make any difference?

Comment: I have noticed that in our projects with a server runtime, maven uses the java runtime configured for that server runtime rather than the project default. So if your project by default is using a server runtime with a java of version 1.6 maven may very well be using THAT runtime. This you can see if you right-click the pom.xml and run a maven command (like mvn install). It should then show you exactly what java runtime it is using (full path to it).

Comment: See my answer - maybe a bug ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: MrD
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0
Created-By: Maven Integration for Eclipse
```

vs (`package`):

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: MrD
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_25
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.2.1
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

I have no java 8 jdk in eclipse (namely in Preferences > Java > Installed JREs). I believe it's a bug - I reported here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=437668

Nevertheless I am not sure it actually *builds* with JDK 8 - maybe it just reports this wrongly ?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue with the version in the manifest file.  It was remedied by changing the eclipse launch parameters to use the intended jvm.  (which can also be done on the command line.)  For me updating eclipse.ini to include:

-vm 
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\javaw.exe

(I chose the jdk version for other reasons too)

Then updated projects using maven plugin and all worked.